# PILLOW throws ValueError: unknown raw mode for given image mode

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I currently use PILLOW to convert some images to base64 for use in a flask API,
It works quite well but for some reason it crashes on a BMP file and I don't know why.

Here is my code :

```
def get_img_base64(filename):
    # Open Image
    image = Image.open(filename)
    # Saving the format
    format = image.format
    buffered = BytesIO()
    image.save(buffered, format)
    img_str = base64.b64encode(buffered.getvalue())
    return "data:image/" + format + ";base64," + img_str.decode()
```

And here is the error I get :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line XXX, in XXX
    imgBase64 = get_img_base64(path)
  File "test.py", line XXX, in get_img_base64
    image.save(buffered, format)
  File "python3.10/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2264, in save
    self._ensure_mutable()
  File "python3.10/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 626, in _ensure_mutable
    self._copy()
  File "python3.10/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 619, in _copy
    self.load()
  File "python3.10/site-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py", line 234, in load
    err_code = decoder.decode(b"")[1]
  File "python3.10/site-packages/PIL/BmpImagePlugin.py", line 326, in decode
    self.set_as_raw(bytes(data), ("P", 0, self.args[-1]))
  File "python3.10/site-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py", line 684, in set_as_raw
    d = Image._getdecoder(self.mode, "raw", (rawmode))
  File "python3.10/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 435, in _getdecoder
    return decoder(mode, *args + extra)
ValueError: unknown raw mode for given image mode
```

I already tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23578891/19353413) by converting the image to "P" but the error `ValueError: unknown raw mode for given image mode` is also showing on this conversion.

[Here is the image in question](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19PfOdObWoxlxJZur2jBgchgGnjeOt7X1/view?usp=sharing)

Here is the reuslt of the `exiftool -v IMG.BMP` command :

```
  ExifToolVersion = 12.40
  FileName = IMG.BMP
  Directory = .
  FileSize = 44978
  FileModifyDate = 1655391432
  FileAccessDate = 1655391514
  FileInodeChangeDate = 1655454712
  FilePermissions = 33272
  FileType = BMP
  FileTypeExtension = BMP
  MIMEType = image/bmp
  + [BinaryData directory, 40 bytes]
  | BMPVersion = 40
  | ImageWidth = 594
  | ImageHeight = 163
  | Planes = 1
  | BitDepth = 8
  | Compression = 1
  | ImageLength = 43900
  | PixelsPerMeterX = 2833
  | PixelsPerMeterY = 2833
  | NumColors = 256
  | NumImportantColors = 256
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was an issue with the PILLOW Library. It should be fixed in the next release as this [PR](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/pull/6384) suggests

Answer (score 3):

Adding this line has solved my problem

```
mask = mask.convert('P')
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't make much sense to me. You appear to have a JPEG, PNG or BMP-encoded image on disk in a file called `filename`. You then decode/decompress it into memory with:

```
image = Image.open(filename)
```

You then re-encode it back to exactly the same format (JPEG/PNG/BMP) as it was using before, but in RAM:

```
format = image.format
buffered = BytesIO()
image.save(buffered, format)
```

What is the point of that? You might just as well simply read the already-encoded file from disk:

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as fd:
   image = fd.read()
```

---

It *might* make sense if you always wanted to encode to a specific format regardless of input format, e.g. always make a PNG or always make a JPEG, but you didn't say that was the case and it might not be sensible to convert PNGs with transparency to JPEG which cannot support transparency.

---

It *might* make sense if you always want to encode to a specific quality setting, but you did't say that either.

---

It *might* make sense if you have some images in a format that `flask` and the user's web browser don't accept, but you didn't say that either.

Comment: Yes, what I failed to mention is that, I have an optional param that I use to sometimes resize the image using pillow and then returning the resized base64 string instead of actually resizing the file.

Comment: I'm guessing the problem will arise either when a palette or transparency is involved, i.e. `mode` contains `P` or `A`. I suggest you print the image mode as soon as you open it and try to see if there is a mode that causes problems. Then click `edit` and add your problematic image and details of what you find.

Comment: The image mode is `L` is that makes sense

Comment: You could check if mode is `L`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/52307690/2836621 and if so, convert to `RGB` with `image = image.convert('RGB')`

Comment: I get the same `ValueError: unknown raw mode for given image mode` on the convert

Comment: I can't really guess much more without 1) seeing the exact code you are running 2) seeing the full error traceback and 3) seeing the image causing the problem - - in its full natural state - i.e. not in reduced resolution nor a screengrab of it nor a JPEG version of a TIFF or similar.

Comment: I woulkd gladly send you the image but I don't know how. The code I posted is minimum viable exemple for you to repoduce the crash if you have the image in question.

Comment: You can maybe use Dropbox, or Google Drive or something similar.

Comment: Or you can click [edit] and add to your question the output from `exiftool -v YOURIMAGE` or from **ImageMagick** `identify -verbose YOURIMAGE`

Comment: I uploaded the image on a google drive, it should be better than the default upload from stackoverflow

Comment: Your image is a BMP with RLE compression. Pillow only supports that from version 9.1.0 You can check your version and what is supported with `python3 -m PIL`

Comment: I have PIL last version `9.1.1` and Python `3.10.4`

Comment: Mmmmm... I think you may need to raise an issue with the PIL developers. It is enough to do `im = Image.open('YOURIMAGE').convert('RGB')` to cause the issue.